# IBM ACE: Running On Premise Independent Integration Server as Windows Service

Tags: ibm-integration-bus, ibm-app-connect

Is there any way to run the On Premise Independent Integration Servers in IBM ACE as a Windows Service.

Comment: Kaushik - Integration server when deployed on a independent VM or laptop needs and is managed by Integration node. Integration node can run as a windows service. You can check your services.msc on windows platform to verify.

Comment: Thanks Rohan for response. But my question is, whether we can run the Independent Integration server alone as windows service in ACE, without associating it to Integration Node.

Comment: I don't think so. Would you be able to tell me the purpose of doing this ?

Comment: we don't want to run this independent integration server under the Integration Node which is associated with Queue Manager. Because when the Queue Manager is down, whole broker is getting down which is affecting the API service running under that independent integration server.

Comment: Don't associate your queue manager with Integration node(broker). Let them run independently, so even if one is down the other keeps running. Note: certain nodes are MQ dependent and can't be used.

Comment: we cant do that, as we are using timer and aggregation nodes in integrations.

Answer (score 0):

Integration server when deployed on an independent VM or laptop or bare metal is managed by Integration node. Integration node can be run as a windows service. You can check your services.msc on windows platform to verify.